# R Shiny build links between tabs WITH sidepanels/conditional panel

Tags: javascript, r, shiny, datatables

This is a question building on top of the discussion on [links between tabs in shiny](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29803310/r-shiny-build-links-between-tabs-with-dt-package/30276145). This solution is just what I need, however my side panel does not change when the table is clicked on.

So my question is how can I make the side panel change too when clicking on the link in the table?

Here is some replicable code:

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$iris_type <- DT::renderDataTable({
    datatable(data.frame(Species=paste0("<a href='#filtered_data'",
                                        "alt='",unique(iris$Species),"'",                                                 
                                        "onclick=\"",
                                        "tabs = $('.tabbable .nav.nav-tabs li');",
                                        "tabs.each(function() {",
                                        "$(this).removeClass('active')",
                                        "});",
                                        "$(tabs[1]).addClass('active');",
                                        "tabsContents = $('.tabbable .tab-content .tab-pane');",
                                        "tabsContents.each(function() {",
                                        "$(this).removeClass('active')",
                                        "});",
                                        "$(tabsContents[1]).addClass('active');",
                                        "$('#filtered_data').trigger('change').trigger('shown');",
                                        "Shiny.onInputChange('species', getAttribute('alt'));",
                                        "\">",
                                        unique(iris$Species),
                                        "</a>")),
                              escape = FALSE)
  })

  output$filtered_data <- DT::renderDataTable({
    if(is.null(input$species)){
      datatable(iris)
    }else{
      datatable(iris[iris$Species %in% input$species, ])
    }
  })
}

ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      conditionalPanel(
        'input.dataset === "Iris Type"',
        helpText("This is the full Iris panel")
      ),
      conditionalPanel(
        'input.dataset === "Filtered Data"',
        helpText("This is the filtered panel")
      ),
      width = 2
    ),
  mainPanel(
    tabsetPanel(
      id = 'dataset',
      tabPanel("Iris Type", DT::dataTableOutput("iris_type")),
      tabPanel("Filtered Data", DT::dataTableOutput("filtered_data"))
    )
  ))
)

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood your question correct, I guess you can just add `"Shiny.onInputChange('dataset', 'Filtered Data');",` to your javascript.

Full code:

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$iris_type <- DT::renderDataTable({
    datatable(data.frame(Species=paste0("<a href='#filtered_data'",
                                        "alt='",unique(iris$Species),"'",                                                 
                                        "onclick=\"",
                                        "tabs = $('.tabbable .nav.nav-tabs li');",
                                        "tabs.each(function() {",
                                        "$(this).removeClass('active')",
                                        "});",
                                        "$(tabs[1]).addClass('active');",
                                        "tabsContents = $('.tabbable .tab-content .tab-pane');",
                                        "tabsContents.each(function() {",
                                        "$(this).removeClass('active')",
                                        "});",
                                        "$(tabsContents[1]).addClass('active');",
                                        "$('#filtered_data').trigger('change').trigger('shown');",
                                        "Shiny.onInputChange('species', getAttribute('alt'));",
                                        "Shiny.onInputChange('dataset', 'Filtered Data');",
                                        "\">",
                                        unique(iris$Species),
                                        "</a>")),
              escape = FALSE)
  })

  output$filtered_data <- DT::renderDataTable({
    if(is.null(input$species)){
      datatable(iris)
    }else{
      datatable(iris[iris$Species %in% input$species, ])
    }
  })
}

ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      conditionalPanel(
        'input.dataset === "Iris Type"',
        helpText("This is the full Iris panel")
      ),
      conditionalPanel(
        'input.dataset === "Filtered Data"',
        helpText("This is the filtered panel")
      ),
      width = 2
    ),
    mainPanel(
      tabsetPanel(
        id = 'dataset',
        tabPanel("Iris Type", DT::dataTableOutput("iris_type")),
        tabPanel("Filtered Data", DT::dataTableOutput("filtered_data"))
      )
    ))
)

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Thank you so much, that was the (admittedly simple) solution I was looking for. Much approciated! :)